# Creating a Login System with existing SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp, authorization

I'm  creating of login system for my xyz.com application .
Ok, I know I have a lot of options :- 
1.Create a new database of users,write logic,make them register etc etc .
2. use Open ID by Google or Facebook.

But I want to use my existing 20 something email id at "xyz.com" domain for login.
Is there a way to authorize "email id and password" if I have SMTP details?

This will save me from maintaining different user id and password database and registering new users separately.

Thanks in advance .

P.S: I m making this application in PHP .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can request an SMTP login name (which may be different than email address, but maybe they are the same) and SMTP password on a login form. Then your PHP script attempts to login to your SMTP server with the provided authentication information, determines the result, disconnects from the SMTP server, answers the form requests depending on the SMTP result. I know that there is a library in Java which can help in doing this, but I cannot help in PHP.